# Feynman Rules in Momentum space

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams

What's the difference between Feynman rules in momentum space for $\phi^3$ theory and for $\phi^4$ theory?

I know it's only a slight difference and perhaps found in the vertex factor? But for some reason I can't seem to find this difference anywhere.

Comment: $\phi^3$ theory has 3 point vertex with factor $i\lambda$ (no 4-point vertex. On the other hand $\phi^4$ theory has a 4-point vertex with factor $i\lambda$ (no 3-point vertex). That's the only difference. Here, I have assumed that the interactions have standard normalizations $\frac{\lambda}{3!}\phi^3$ and $\frac{\lambda}{4!} \phi^4$ respectively.

Comment: Oh right cool. I knew this but thought maybe one of them was $-i\lambda$.

Comment: They are typically both $-i\lambda$.

Comment: It depends on the sign of the interaction. I agree with @JeffDror. For $\phi^4$ we would have a negative sign and hence $-i\lambda$. $\phi^3$ isn't really well-defined as a theory (no positive-definite Hamiltonian) so the sign can be chosen arbitrarily.